# Windows 8.1 Bing Maps Directions SDK crashing

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1, bing-maps

In my windows 8.1 app I use the Bing Maps SDK to get driving directions to a location.

When I attempt to call this line

```
Waypoint begin = new Waypoint(new Location(current.Latitude, current.Longitude));
```

I get a `System.TypeLoadException` with the error

```
Requested Windows Runtime type 'Bing.Maps.Directions.Waypoint' is not registered
```

If I remove and reload the Bing Maps dll from the project it starts working again however when I package the app up for release it still crashes. If I close the project and reopen it I get this crash again.

this is the stack trace

```
System.TypeLoadException: Requested Windows Runtime type 'Bing.Maps.Directions.Waypoint' is not registered. ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Class not registered 

  (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG))
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.StubHelpers.StubHelpers.GetWinRTFactoryObject(IntPtr pCPCMD)
   at Bing.Maps.Directions.Waypoint..ctor(Location location)
   at MobileMap_Win8.Pages.CurrentIncident.NavigationPage.<CalculateRoute>d__18.MoveNext()
```

The map itself displays fine, `current` has a valid location so I dont know what the problem is.

this is the SDK I downloaded

https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/224eb93a-ebc4-46ba-9be7-90ee777ad9e1

Comment: This MS Map SDK needs an update. Facing similar problems in my project.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to build the app in Release mode before packaging. If you leave it in Debug mode it will cause issues like this.